Stuck on confirm page after OAuth redirect(Nuxt/Supabase/Ionic)
I've started to build a project with Nuxt, Supabase and Ionic. Since i want to build a PWA in the end of this journey i want my users to sign in with OAuth. So I did the necessary steps of creating Supabase project, enabled google provider, generated credentials on google cloud developer console etc.
Since nuxt supabase module requires to create login and confirm pages i mostly copy pasted the code from the nuxt/supabase docs. Now the authentication works ok, after that i'm correctly redirected to confirm page and then I'm stuck there, no error in console or server console. So i've tried to use the debugger to see the result of navigateTo which is undefined ...when i went deeper i saw that on checking the routeguards I'm getting the Navigation cancelled with new navigation error. So i thoght....ok maybe i need to use the ionRouter instead of navigateTo. But that was working the same as the navigateTo method ....still stuck on the confirm page.
login.vue
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Dogiary</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">
      <div class="min-h-full flex flex-col justify-center sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <h2 class="my-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold">
          Sign in to your account
        </h2>
        <div class="px-6">
          <ion-button expand="full" class="h-[60px]" @click="signIn">
            <ion-icon slot="start" :icon="ioniconsLogoGoogle"></ion-icon>
            Google
          </ion-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script setup>
const supabaseClient = useSupabaseClient()
const signIn = () => {
  supabaseClient.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: "google",
    options: {
      redirectTo: window.location.origin + '/confirm',
    }
  })
}
</script>

confirm.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
const user = useSupabaseUser()

watch(user, () => {
  if (user.value) {
    return navigateTo('/')
  }
}, { immediate: true })
</script>
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-content>
      Authenticating...
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>


There might be some logs on the auth side. Not sure how to help you otherwise with this amount of context.

I've updated the question a bit. If you need anything more let me know. Anyway, the auth works ok as i am redirected to that confirm.vue page. Problem is that im stuck there :(
